# std::aligned_alloc and aligned operator new in C++ 17

Tags: memory-management, c++17, memory-alignment

I have questions regarding the std::aligned_alloc and aligned operator new in C++ 17.

Do I understand correctly that the aligned version of `operator new` works only on the oblects that were declared as aligned? i.e

```
struct alignas(16) aligned_shorts
{
short shorts[8];
};
```

Only then  `new aligned_shorts[7]` will result in aligned memory?

But what if I want a aligned dynamic array i. e of ints?

```
int *aligned_ints;// want aligned dynamic array
```

Can be std::aligned_alloc used for that? And if I need to overalign (e. g. for vectorization) I would need to overallocate/pad:

```
int* allocate_aligned_ints(int num, int align_as)
{
int needed_memory=num*sizeof(int);
if((needed_memory% align_as) > 0)//
needed_memory+=(align_as- needed_memory% align_as);//pad if neccessary
return static_cast<int*>(std::aligned_alloc(align_as, needed_memory));
}
```

Comment: "*I would need to overallocate/pad a bit*" Why would `std::aligned_alloc` even exist if you needed to do that?

Comment: @NicolBolas I had overalignment in mind. Clarified that with the edit.

Comment: I'm confused, why not just use `std::aligned_alloc(align_as, needed_memory)`? Why the explict 16 in your example?

Comment: @Frank you are right, inattention on my part. Corrected.